# Transform Java 7 code that filters collection by distance into stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a working code that takes a collection and applies a filter based on a certain distance.

For example, the second point in the list has to be at least 1KM apart from the first, and any items in between those two are removed.
The input is already sorted.

```
private List<Point> filterByMinimumDistance(List<Point> points, double minDistance) {
    Point reference = points.get(0);
    List<Point> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
    filtered.add(reference);
    for (Point point : points) {
        double distance = getDistance(reference, point);
        if (distance >= minDistance) {
            reference = point;
            filtered.add(point);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}

private double getDistance(Point p1, Point p2) {
    double dx = p1.getX() - p2.getX();
    double dy = p1.getY() - p2.getY();
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

So far I haven't been able to come up with something that replaces this with a fancier stream solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Just because it's "fancier"...?

Comment: @Michael Not because of that, but it would improve on my skills. I'm just trying to learn here

Comment: A semantic suggestion:  The first point in the list is different than the rest: it shouldn't be part of the list.  Pass it in as a separate parameter.

Comment: Actually, after reading your code again, you are assigning a new `reference` if the distance is larger than the minimum.  What's the actual algorithm here trying to do?

Comment: @NathanMerrill The code makes sure that there are no elements too close to each other. For example, the second point has to be at least 1KM apart from the first, and any other points in between those two are removed

Comment: @victorantunes what happens if I have 3 points:  `(0,0)`, `(0, 2KM)`, and `(0,1)` (in that order)?  That'll pass your check, even though the first and the third point are too close.

Comment: @NathanMerrill yes they would, but the input is sorted prior to calling this method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153700/discussion-between-nathan-merrill-and-victorantunes).

Comment: I think this is not a good candidate for using a stream. A stream should not rely on side effects from previous iterations.

Comment: `reference` should be _effectively final_, shouldn't it?

Comment: Your algorithm will *never* include the first point in your filtered list. Is that intentional?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I made a mistake copying the code. This is a stub, not real production code. Sorry. The first point is always added

Comment: I think what you're looking for is some kind of Collector. Something like Java's `toList()` collector, but one which removes adjacent points that are too close to each other. It seems too much trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could create a custom collector for these points:

```
 private static Collector<Point, ?, List<Point>> customCollector(double minDistance) {

    class Acc {

        private Point reference = null;

        private List<Point> filtered = new ArrayList<>();

        void accumulate(Point elem) {
            if (reference == null) {
                reference = elem;
            }

            double distance = getDistance(reference, elem);

            if (distance >= minDistance) {
                reference = elem;
                filtered.add(elem);
            }
        }

        Acc combine(Acc other) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not for parallel");
        }

        List<Point> finisher() {
            return filtered;
        }

        private double getDistance(Point p1, Point p2) {
            double dx = p1.getX() - p2.getX();
            double dy = p1.getY() - p2.getY();
            return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        }

    }

    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::accumulate, Acc::combine, Acc::finisher);
}
```

Usage would be :

```
points.stream().collect(customCollector(minDistance));
```

Also I might have to think a bit more about the `combiner` here as I am not quite sure it could be correctly implemented like this:

```
Acc combine(Acc other) {
     filtered.addAll(other.filtered);
     return this;
}
```

Comment: It really does seem like a lot of trouble. Though, I wouldn't bother with the combiner, since parallelizing this would break the constraint that requires the points to be in sequential order. But thanks for the answer! I wasn't sure of how to implement a custom collector, but you sure pointed me in the correct direction

Comment: @victorantunes sequential or parallel does not influence the order of the results btw, I would still add a combiner once I'm done thinking about it

Comment: It's a shame that `Collector` doesn't really lend itself to being directly implemented and that you need the static method.